# Is it safe to go into the directory where a program is installed?

Tags: linux, windows, path

Can I mess something up when I go into a programs install path? For example, could I break or alter something by accidentally moving a file from there into a different folder?

Comment: Thinks are usually not broken by merely _looking_ at them. Obviously if you move/delete random files or folders you could break a program's functionality. Just don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the specific file nor program. You could easily damage the program installed moving the wrong file.

Best advice for inexperienced people, leave the program folder alone and let Windows and Installers manage programs folder contents.

If you are in control of a program, you can easily change file attributes to prevent deletion of a file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will it at least be obvious when I change something (Will the program for example not start?), or can the difference be subtle?

Comment: It depends on what you move or delete.  A program may not start or other damage, depending on what was moved / deleted.

Comment: The problems caused could be subtle as most programs have hundreds of features if not more.  Most people use maybe 50% of a program, so you could damage a function you don't normally use and wouldn't detect the problem until you used that specific function.

Comment: What if, for example, a file with code or with a configuration gets deleted, and the program is running a process, where that file is needed? Will the program then crash?

Comment: It depends on the program and how it was constructed.  Best thing as I noted is not to mess with such folders.

Comment: Would it be possible though to change particular aspects of the program to be different by deleting/moving a file? For example, could a characters movement speed in a video game be altered by not editing, but removing a file? Sorry btw for the very newbie questions.

Comment: You would need variables in the program code to do what you want.

Comment: You mean I would need to change variables in the code to do that, so removing a file wouldn't be able to cause this to happen?

Comment: Yes, the program code would need changes to secure files and not allow them to be deleted or altered

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't express myself clearly. The question was: if I would remove a file from, let's say a video games folder, could that change something like the characters movement speed.

Comment: You can change file attributes to secure files

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about deleting or moving things by mistake,
then ensure that there are confirmation dialogs for such actions.

For deletes, this is turned on by right-click on the
Recycle Bin icon, select Properties, and ensure that
"Display delete confirmation dialog" is set.

For moves, you can use the github project of
[DragDropConfirm](https://github.com/broken-e/DragDropConfirm).
You need to download it using the Code button to select Download zip,
unzip it, go into the Installer folder and execute the
`DragDropConfirm_installer.exe`.

For details see the article
[How to confirm file/folder move on drag & drop on Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/confirm-on-drag-drop-windows-10/).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations!

Comment: Does a similar project exist for Linux as well?

Comment: Not as far as I know - [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126730/how-to-enable-confirmation-dialog-on-files-delete-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer